# Responsive show/hide links on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, show-hide

I would like to have a list of show/hide links that show divs occupying the same space, and able to be responsive. 
My list appear on left and show content on right.
The idea is that when I click on Link 1, then content #1 will show up, and when I click on Link 2, then content #1 will disappear and content #2 will take it's place.

When loading the page on small and mobile screen, I would like to get content #1 showing up under Link 1 when clicking on it, and content 1 pushs link 2 down. And so on, content #2 showing up under Link 2, and pushs link 3 down…

I am working on Wordpress and Bootstrap, using my own theme. I don't reject to use .php file to achieve that. So far, I have tried this in html, css and js. Since I got stuck trying to get this reponsive, I am open to get a diffent method if necessary. But I would like to be able to fill the content and links name from Wordpress.

Here is my initial code

```js
$(function () {
  $("a[id^='link']").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = this.id.replace("link", "");
    $(".panel").hide();
    $("#panel" + index).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.side-nav {
  font-size: calc(18px + 3vw);
}

.panel {
  font-size: calc(18px + 1vw);
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div id="side-nav-container">

  <div class="side-nav">
    <a id="link1 " href="# ">Link 1</a>
    <a id="link2 " href="# ">Link 2>/a>
  </div>

  <div id="side-nav-content">
    <div id="panel1 " class="panel ">Content 1</div>
    <div id="panel2 " class="panel ">Content 2</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

new code

```js
$('#myTabs a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

```css
.tab-content {
  font-size: calc(12px + .99vw);
}

.nav-tab-list {
  font-size: calc(18px + 1vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="nav-tab-list col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-xs-12">
      <ul class="nav nav-stacked" role="tablist">
        <li class="active" role="presentation"><a role="tab" href="#home" aria-controls="home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-5 col-xs-12">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel">Bonjour</div>
        <div id="profile" class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel">Hello</div>
        <div id="messages" class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel">Au revoir</div>
        <div id="settings" class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel">Goodbye</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you're using Bootstrap, assuming it's V3, you can use their Tabs system. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs

Comment: @Ishio , thanks. I would have to use this on different pages of my site, and show different number and names of tab. Do you think this is possible if I use the Tabs system, and still possible to fill the content in Wordpress?

Comment: With the way you have it set up, you can use custom repeater fields and enter the content within the admin. This will require the possible use of a plugin, unless you're comfortable writing one out yourself. One that you can use is Advanced Custom Fields.

Comment: Ok @Ishio ! How can I use custom repeater fields? I don't want to repeat the same tabs, I would like to have the same system on few pages, but with different amount of tabs and different tabs' name.

Comment: I actually put the Bootstrap Tabs in place, as it is described. It's working on desktop screen, but when I load the page on mobile, all tabs show up the content of the first tab. Do you know why is that?

Comment: This would have to do with your styles. Check the CSS for them

Comment: Yes, it is fixed! But when mobile screen is loaded, the content of the stacked tabs should toggles down its own tab. For example : I click on "Tab1" > it toggles down "Content #1" > "Content #1" pushs "Tab2" down. Because otherwise, if I have 20 tabs, when clicking on them (on mobile) it shows up the content all the way under all the tabs. It is not very practicle if I have to scroll up and down every time clicking on a tab.

Comment: Right, without knowing how the code looks now, in your initial post, that's how it would function in mobile. What you could try doing is duplicating and having a tabs blocko n desktop and a tabs block on mobile, the mobile one appearing like in the bootstrap example and the desktop one appearing like in your initial post

Comment: But the Bootstrap example doesn't toggle down the content under its own tab, but under all tabs. I have edited my post with new code.

Comment: What is your javascript?

Comment: Ups sorry I forgot to paste it, I updated my post. I am just not sure where my js should be, because it doesn't seem to make any difference if it is present or not, it is still working like I described it.